# adding a proxy to git config through command line without proxy user / proxy pwd

Tags: git

I have this proxy defined in my `/git/.gitconfig`

```
[http "https://dpl.tdk.com"]
    proxy = http://10.0.11.25:8080
```

but somehow does not appear when I do `git config --list`

I want to add it manually, but I don't know how to do it, since there is a `<username>:<password>` that I don't have

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<username>:<password>@10.0.14.15:8080
```

Comment: Did you mean "in my `.git/config` file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git config --global http.proxy http://10.0.14.15:8080

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
git config --global http."https://dpl.tdk.com".proxy http://<username>:<password>@10.0.14.15:8080
```

For `<username>` and `<password>` ask your network admins.